# Cannot install app in dev iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

With Xcode 7 I cannot install app on dev iPhone with iOS 9 GM.
App is marked as installed but it is not visible in springboard.
Provision profiles seem ok. I'm using core-plot, don't know if it is an architecture issues.

Device log

```
>     Sep 11 18:35:53 Davides-iPhone streaming_zip_conduit[274] <Warning>: LaunchServices: installing app for existing placeholder
> <LSApplicationProxy: 0x135523f60> com.protoscar.HCD2 <(null) *Not
> found in database*>
>     Sep 11 18:35:53 Davides-iPhone streaming_zip_conduit[274] <Warning>: LaunchServices: Not creating progress for
> <LSApplicationProxy: 0x135523f60> com.protoscar.HCD2 <(null) *Not
> found in database*> since it is not a placeholder.
>     Sep 11 18:35:53 Davides-iPhone installd[52] <Notice>: 0x1704b3000 -[MIClientConnection installPath:withOptions:completion:]: Install of "/var/mobile/Media/PublicStaging/HCD2.app" type Developer requested by
> streaming_zip_conduit (pid 274)
>     Sep 11 18:35:53 Davides-iPhone installd[52] <Notice>: 0x17148f000 -[MIInstaller performInstallationWithError:]: Installing <MIInstallableBundle ID=com.protoscar.HCD2; Version=14,
> ShortVersion=1.0>
>     Sep 11 18:35:53 Davides-iPhone profiled[151] <Notice>: (Note ) MC: Provisioning profiles changed
>     Sep 11 18:35:53 Davides-iPhone profiled[151] <Notice>: (Note ) MC: Updating MIS trust...
>     Sep 11 18:35:53 Davides-iPhone installd[52] <Error>:  SecTrustEvaluate  [leaf IssuerCommonName SubjectCommonName]
>     Sep 11 18:35:53 Davides-iPhone installd[52] <Notice>: 0x17148f000 -[MIContainer makeContainerLiveReplacingContainer:reason:withError:]: Made container live for com.protoscar.HCD2 at
> /private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/5DF14AF7-C8F4-4CBE-B081-C5BD046EFD27
>     Sep 11 18:35:53 Davides-iPhone installd[52] <Notice>: 0x17148f000 -[MIContainer makeContainerLiveReplacingContainer:reason:withError:]: Made container live for com.protoscar.HCD2 at
> /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/E83B05A4-ACC1-42E2-A3AA-942A2CDB131F
>     Sep 11 18:35:54 Davides-iPhone installd[52] <Notice>: 0x17148f000 -[MIInstaller performInstallationWithError:]: Install Successful; Staging: 0.01s; Waiting: 0.00s; Preflight/Patch: 0.09s, Verifying:
> 0.09s; Overall: 0.35s
```

Answer (score 6):

Fixed. I removed the provision profiles, rebooted the device and now the app install without problem.

Comment: You are right, but I have to wait two days for that.

Comment: Hi, i have some trouble with installation with core plot release 2.0. Can you help me?

Comment: I had trouble too,  try to follow installations guide and check architecture settings. I fix it by compiling myself the master branch

Comment: This worked for me too. I deleted the old provisions and made new ones with new names to make sure I'm using the new version, not the old version stored in xcode.